# Why isn't MySQL REGEXP filtering out these values?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, string, where-clause

So I'm trying to find what "special characters" have been used in my customer names. I'm going through updating this query to find them all one-by-one, but it's still showing all customers with a - despite me trying to exlude that in the query.

Here's the query I'm using:

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE name REGEXP "[^\da-zA-Z\ \.\&\-\(\)\,]+";
```

This customer (and many others with a dash) are still showing in the query results:

```
Test-able Software Ltd
```

What am I missing? Based on that regexp, shouldn't that one be excluded from the query results?

Testing it on https://regex101.com/r/AMOwaj/1 shows there is no match.

**Edit** - So I want to FIND any which have characters other than the ones in the regex character set. Not exclude any which do have these characters.

Answer (score 1):

Your code checks if the string contains any character that does not belong to the character class, while you want to ensure that none does belong to it.

You can use `^` and `$` to check the while string at once:

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE name REGEXP '^[^\da-zA-Z .&\-(),]+$';
```

This would probably be simpler expressed with `NOT`, and without negating the character class:

```
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE name NOT REGEXP '[\da-zA-Z .&\-(),]';
```

Note that you don't need to escape all the characters within the character class, except probably for `-`.

Comment: i wonder, if you don't escape the hyphen, how does it treat `a-z` vs `&-(`?  The hyphen probably needs to be escaped.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey: ah yes, that's a good point. Updated, thank you.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I should have been clearer in my question - edited.

Edit - So I want to FIND any which have characters other than the ones in the regex character set. Not exclude any which do have these characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]` to match digits irrespective of MySQL version.

Use the hyphen where it can't make part of a range construction.

Fix the expression as

```sql
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE name REGEXP "[^0-9a-zA-Z .&(),-]+";
```

If the entire text should match this pattern, enclose with `^` / `$`:

```sql
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE name REGEXP "^[^0-9a-zA-Z .&(),-]+$";
```

Answer (score 0):

`-` implies a range *except* if it is first.  (Well, after the "not" (`^`).)

So use

```
"[^-0-9a-zA-Z .&(),]"
```

I removed the `+` at the end because you don't really care how many; this way it will stop after finding one.

Comment: Even when it's escaped like in mine? Or does MySQL ignore the escape sequence? :/

Comment: @BT643 - Escapes do not hurt.  Escaping `\` is mandatory (obviously).  And probably `]`, `^`, `-`.  But I _think_ the rest are optional.  Inside a "character class", there are not many characters that would confuse the parsing if they were not escaped.  Outside a character class (but still in a regexp), there are a lot of characters that need to be escaped.